# How to set SqlParameter directly without looping through list of parameters

Tags: c#, parameters

I'm currently setting the properties of a `SqlParameter` by looping through a list of all `SqlParameter`s like this, but would like to set them without the loop.

```
foreach (SqlParameter param in parameters)
{
    if (param.ParameterName.Contains("AvailableVals"))
    {
        param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.TypeName = "dbo.udtGenExpression";
        param.Value = inputValues.GetIdTable();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to set the `AvailableVals` parameter by name without iterating through the list of parameters? Thanks

Comment: no it is not possible, you can use linq but it will still be internally iterating the list

Comment: You could always set the values appropriately when *adding* the parameter? then you don't need to loop... but frankly: a `foreach` over the parameters is **nothing**; it is cheap *anyway*, but when compared to a DB hop - it literally doesn't matter; there is no harm in this loop, so just leave it alone?

Comment: This is indeed required in this *isolated* example. However, if you need to set several parameters, a more readable alternative is probably more adviseable. For instance, you could use the `ToDictionary` extension method to easily create a name-to-SqlParameter object mapping (essentially, iterating over the list of parameters just once) and then indeed access the param objects by their name.

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Comment: Is the exact name of the parameter `"AvailableVals"`?

Comment: @spodger Yes that is the exact name.

Comment: In which case I would have given an answer similar to @CDove's below. If you know it exists you can just access it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Most efficiently, you can just directly call the parameter by name using the functions of the `SqlParameterCollection`:

```
if(parameters.Contains("AvailableVals"))
{                     
                parameters.Item("AvailableVals").SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                parameters.Item("AvailableVals").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                parameters.Item("AvailableVals").TypeName = "dbo.udtGenExpression";
                parameters.Item("AvailableVals").Value = inputValues.GetIdTable();
}
```

Note that this will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` if the parameter doesn't exist and you don't operate conditionally.  Either `catch` it and do something useful, or validate the `SqlParameter` first as I have done in the example.